# How can I pass a parameter to a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I'm going to use a lamda expression to new a dictionary<string, string> with parameter. The value of the dictionary is string but it is serialized by another dictionary<string, string>.

For example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dicPerson = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dicPerson .Add("Name", "Tom");
dicPerson .Add("Married", "false");

Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("Person", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dicPerson));

void CreateDictionary()
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Person", "{\"Name\":\"Tom\", \"Married\":\"false\"}"}
    };
}

void CreateDictionary(string name, bool married)
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Person", "{\"Name\":\"{name}\", \"Married\":\"{married}\"}"}
    };
}
```

I have a method to create the dictionary by initiate the key-value pair by hardcoding. But it is non convenient, seeing the first CreateDictionary() method without parameters. To create the dictionary with different purpose, want to pass the values like CreateDictionary(string name, bool married) method. The code I used doesn't work as it will think {name} as string by default.

Is it possible if I pass the name or bool Married value to the dictionary created inside instead of hardcoding "Tom" or "false"?

Comment: There's a lot of context missing here. I've overall very confused about what you're trying to accomplish here. At the very least, please [edit] your post with a [mre] - I have no idea what `param1/param2` and `CallMethod` are. I don't know why you have an anonymous method inside `MyMethod`, which you don't seem to invoke, and that doesn't have any parameters. I don't know how anything in the `MyMethod` body relates to the lines above it.

Comment: Did you consider creating a class `Person` with properties `Name` and ' Married` for this?

Comment: To address your question: You need to use string interpolation (`$"..."`) to ensure that `{name}` and `{married}` are interpreted as placeholders for variable values. When using string interpolation, you also need to escape the stand-alone `{`/`}` characters by doubling them (`{{`/`}}`): `$"{{\"Name\":\"{name}\", \"Married\":\"{married}\"}}"`. I do not see how this approach will be combined with the serialization, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you just want to refactor method CreateDictionary to accept parameter name and married right?
You can try this code:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> CreateDictionary(string name, bool married)
        {
            var dicPerson = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Name", name },
                { "Married", married.ToString() }
            };

            var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Person", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dicPerson) }
            };

            return dic;
        }
```

Here is sample how you call the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var personDictionary = CreateDictionary("Tom", false);
            string serializedDictionary = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personDictionary);
            Console.WriteLine(serializedDictionary);
        }
```